# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, facebook-authentication

I am getting this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a facebook_application_id string.`, Yes i have checked [Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a `facebook_application_id` string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665890/facebook-provider-unconfigured-make-sure-to-add-a-facebook-application-id-str) but i does not solve the problem.

string file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">meter</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">my_id</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbmy_fb_login_protocol_scheme</string>
    <string name="twitter_consumer_key" translatable="false">MY_TWITTER_KEY</string>
    <string name="twitter_consumer_secret" translatable="false">MY_SECRET</string>
</resources>
```

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="meter.meter" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data tools:replace="android:value" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMY_ID_HERE"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Project build Gradle:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "meter.meter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    // Find the latest Facebook SDK releases here: http
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0'

    // Required only if Twitter login support is required
    // Find the latest Twitter SDK releases here: https
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Exception:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: meter.meter, PID: 11557
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{meter.meter/meter.meter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a `facebook_application_id` string. See the docs for more info: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#facebook
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a `facebook_application_id` string. See the docs for more info: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#facebook
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.Preconditions.checkConfigured(Preconditions.java:90)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI$IdpConfig$FacebookBuilder.<init>(AuthUI.java:1026)
        at meter.meter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Add below:
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">APP_ID</string>
    <!-- Facebook Application ID, prefixed by 'fb'. Enables Chrome Custom tabs. -->
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbAPP_ID</string>

in your strings.xml

Pay attention to the names in the above, and the ones you have defined currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

Add

`<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">APP_ID</string>
<!-- Facebook Application ID, prefixed by 'fb'. Enables Chrome Custom tabs. -->
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbAPP_ID</string> in your strings.xml`

Pay attention to the names :)
The logs also gives you a link to follow to resolve your issue.

Comment: please share your current strings.xml file. I am again saying, Please Pay attention to the NAMES

Comment: tried changing name from `facebook_app_id` to `facebook_application_id` ,it worked :) thank you :)