# Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a 'facebook_application_id' string

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I a trying firebase authentication with pre-build UI I follow all step but  I am getting following error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dhingana, PID: 23811
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectname/com.example.dhingana.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a `facebook_application_id` string. See the docs for more info:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Name</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id" translatable="false">id</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbid</string>
</resources>
```

This is string.xml file

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" tools:replace="android:value" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                  android:configChanges=
                          "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider230*******08"
                  android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                  android:exported="true" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I have tried so many things on the internet but those not work.
If I remove facebook option from provider list everything work fine just on adding of Facebook this error happen

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665890/facebook-provider-unconfigured-make-sure-to-add-a-facebook-application-id-str?rq=1?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu No this does not  help

Answer (score 0):

I think `<meta-data>...</meta-data>` tag should not be nested in `<activity/>`. That may cause error. Also, I believe `CustomTabActivity` should look like this

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
</intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

And fb_login_protocol_scheme string is `<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbYOUR_APP_ID</string>`

Comment: I change custom activity as per you suggest but not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove this tag from the activity tag and and write it after completion of activity tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Comment: Update, Same error with this Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.